# What are these weird vector lines on my fonts in iOS Safari? See screenshot and snippet

Tags: fonts, mobile-safari

While doing some work on a mobile site in iOS Safari I zoomed in and noticed these weird vector lines on some text. This is on iOS 16.6.1. This is the CSS font stack I am using:

```
font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Lucida Grande', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Liberation Sans', sans-serif
```

How do I get rid of this? The don't appear anywhere else (it looks normal on FireFox and Chrome).

[image]

```html
<style>
button{
background-color:#1b75d0;
color:#ffffff;
font-size:18px;
border-width:0;
padding:5px;
margin:0;
paint-order: fill markers stroke;
font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Lucida Grande', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Liberation Sans', sans-serif;
}
</style>

<button>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

After setting the CSS property `paint-order` to `normal`, the weird lines went away.